# WPF: Checking if user has changed one of the controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF window with about 30 controls on it (text and comboboxes). There is no binding, I just populate them from a dictionary in Loaded event. I need to be able to know if user has changed any of them. Is there a way to do it other than setting a flag in 30 "Changed" events?
I tried to research it and saw a lot of info on implementing IsDirty property but I am not sure if it is applicable to my simple unbound window.

Comment: You should definitely use binding. Why would you NOT use it? And if that is the case, take a look at the `BindingGroup` class.

Comment: What do you define as `Changed`. Are these Textboxes? Checkboxes?

Comment: _"There is no binding"_ -- well, _there's_ your problem. There are lots of ways to detect when a user has provided input. You need to do some research, try something, and post a question if and when you can provide a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, and a _specific_ question asking about some specific difficulty you had with that attempt.

Comment: Michael, there are Textboxes, ComboBoxes and Checkboxes/

Comment: Heltonbiker, what is the benefit of binding in this case? I would need to specify a binding field for each control, would need to write more code, while this way I populate all controls with a very simple loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one changed event handler that is attached to all 30 events.